# In a table how can I nest multiple rows of cells within a single cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

My table consists of 6 columns and 5 rows. In each row, the 5th column needs to hold multiple cells stacked on top of each other. Is there a way I can do this without nesting a new table in the 5th column of each row?

```
    <tr>
        <td><img class="image" src="Posters/suicidesquad-poster1.jpg"></td>
        <td>Suicide Squad</td>
        <td>PG-13</td>
        <td>2 Hour(s) 3 Minutes</td>
        <!-- Here I need to add two rows within the 5th column 

            <td>Row One </td>
            <td>Row Two </td>

        The sixth column will be the same as the others --> 

        <td>CC, DV</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Now that you have an answer, think about _why_ you want it split like that. What is the _structure_ of the data in column 5?  Using a single `td` that contains 2 divs _may_ be a more appropriate representation of the data, and those can easily be stacked within the table cell.  Get the _structure_ right first, then make it look the way you want with CSS; don't concentrate on the look at the start -- you will likely end up with something that is unmaintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

You can put 2 DIVs  into each of those TDs:

```
<tr>
    <td><img class="image" src="Posters/suicidesquad-poster1.jpg"></td>
    <td>Suicide Squad</td>
    <td>PG-13</td>
    <td>2 Hour(s) 3 Minutes</td>
    <td>
       <div class="my_extra_cells">Row One</div>
       <div class="my_extra_cells">Row Two </div>
    </td>
    <td>CC, DV</td>
</tr>
```

Just create a CSS rule for `.my_extra_cells` to have it look as you like.

Comment: please note: I changed some details in the code (I had 5 columns before, now 6)

Comment: This should easily be the **correct solution**. No need to **tweak** individual `<td>` with `rowspan`s. In case of multiple values for a cell, we can loop through the dataset and the html will take care of the rest. The fun part will be : **we can send as many values as need be**. All will get neatly placed in the same cell one under the other. A similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70184600)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `rowspan` instead of `divs`, I believe you want this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <img class="image" src="Posters/suicidesquad-poster1.jpg">
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">Suicide Squad</td>
    <td rowspan="2">PG-13</td>
    <td Rowspan="2">2 Hour(s) 3 Minutes</td>
    <td>Row One</td>
    <td rowspan="2">CC, DV</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ya the question is/was unclear to me, but I bet this what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Yes you use the `col-span` or `row-span`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Two High</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Two High</td>
        <td>Single</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Single</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will give you the desired effect, in reality it "merges" `<td>`'s together while preserving the ones you want to appear singular.

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp) for further information around this attribute.

Comment: This almost works but my sixth column is now in a row by itself

Comment: Now add a `rowspan=5` to that guy, if the whole thing is 5 high. Remember to count your rows as singular when using this. Meaning if something has a row span of 2, it counts as 2 rows.